Setting placehead=empty still inserts the inter-paragraph whitespace
Consider the following code:
\setupwhitespace[big]
\setuppapersize[S4]
\definehead[MyHead][subsection][page=yes,placehead=empty]
\setupheadertexts[]
\setupheadertexts[MyHead][\userpagenumber]

\showframe
\starttext
\startMyHead[title={Some Title Text}]
  \input knuth
\stopMyHead
\page
\input knuth
\stoptext

I am using \showframe to make it easier to see the whitespace. The two \input knuth are typeset differently: Page 1 (generated by \startMyHead) has some whitespace before the first paragraph, while in Pages 2, 3, and 4 (Page 2 is the second page in MyHead, Pages 3 and 4 are outside MyHead), the text touches the upper border.
Using placehead=hidden removes the extra space, but in that case \getmarking[MyHead] does not work any more. Can I do anything to avoid the extra space before the first paragraph in MyHead with placehead=empty? I have tried before=\relax, after=\relax (I hope these would consume the extra whitespace), but I do not see any difference.
I am using ConTeXt from TeXLive 2024, context --version shows the following:
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.06
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: $HOME/.texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2024.02.27 09:18
mtx-context     | main context file: $HOME/.texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2024.02.27 09:18


You can see it with \showmakeup[vglue], but I don't know what is causing it. It seems to work with placehead=hidden together with
\setupheadertexts[{\placerawheadtext[MyHead]}][\userpagenumber]


So, the complete test I used is:
% \showmakeup[vglue]

\setupwhitespace[big]
\setuppapersize[S4]
\definehead
  [MyHead]
  [subsection]
  [page=yes,
   placehead=hidden]

\setupheadertexts[]
\setupheadertexts[{\placerawheadtext[MyHead]}][\userpagenumber]

\showframe

\starttext
\startMyHead[title={Some Title Text}]
  \input knuth
\stopMyHead
\page
\input knuth

\page

\startMyHead[title={Some NEW Title Text}]
  \input knuth
\stopMyHead
\page
\input knuth

\stoptext

Result:

I don't know if there are any side effects of this, but I can ask Hans about it next time I talk to him.
Edit
Now I have talked to Hans, and he suggested that one can also use \flushatnextpar. The relevant part:
\startMyHead[title={Some Title Text}]
\flushatnextpar{\synchronizehead{MyHead}}
\input knuth
\stopMyHead

placehead=hidden defines the head, but you have to place the anchor manually. The anchor is needed to register the mark, reference, list entry and so on.
placehead=empty actually does place that anchor, but does not render the title. The extra space comes from that invisible node.

I just tested your code, and it seems that setting placehead=hidden breaks page=yes. To reproduce, duplicate the \startMyHead...\stopMyHead block, and I see no page break before the second \startMyHead.

\fliushatnextpar{\synchronizehead{MyHead}} does not seem to help with the page break, either. Duplicate the MyHead block and I see them still connected (no page break in between).

No, placehead=hidden does not break page=yes, there should just not be any action related to placement with it. Only registering. You have to do add the page yourself. (The hidden is mainly there if you want to make fancy things.). Also, do you really need a section at all, or would just setting up the header also work here?

Write this twice: \startMyHead[title={Test}] \flushatnextpar{\synchronizehead{MyHead}} \input knuth \stopMyHead, and I do not see a page break between them. I guess you mean that this is the expected behaviour? I do not really need a section, but I followed the advice from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62187/providing-arguments-to-a-start-stop and thought reusing \definehead is a good idea. If you think I am approaching the problem in the wrong way, please do guide me to the right direction.

I do not understand what you really want to do. If you only want to put something in the header you can use a marking and add it to the header, and then just update it.

Okay, I am following the ConTeXt slides tutorial (https://github.com/adityam/context-slides-example) and trying to do my own customisations. I like the way that each slide is enclosed in \startslide and \endslide, and the fact that I can specify the title in \startslide. I really just care about the syntax, and whether it is implemented using \definehead does not really matter.

Maybe that should go into a new question. With an example that also shows the output you want...

I am the author of the linked tutorial.  I piggy-backed on the head mechanism because to me a slide title naturally looked like a heading. If you want to use the mark mechanism to place the slide title, then the simplest thing is to just use \setmarking and \getmarking to set and get the mark.
